# How to unlock table in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I created table in SQL Server 2012 and when I execute

```
select * from tableName
```

it is taking a long time and some time returns no result.

Currently it has only 1 row. After searching I know it is being locked so please help how to unlock it or drop it?

Comment: What process is locking it? Run your select *, then as it's waiting run 'exec sp_who2'. The BlkBy column will show your select statement being blocked by another process number. To clear that other process you want to run 'KILL 32' (for process 32 as an example)

Comment: Hi Rich Benner,
I have killed session using below approach and now when i fire select * query it giving me result.Is it the right approach ? Won't it cause any issue in future ?

Comment: Depends entirely on the session that you killed. You could take a look at either editing the code that was causing locking so that it doesn't take a lock or you could look at isolation levels within SQL which would allow you to get around this.

Comment: Ok Thank you Rich Benner.

Comment: Hello Rich,
Today I again same problem with another table.This tables has been created 6 back , never face any issue in past.Could you please suggest me the temporary solution ?

Comment: see my first answer, run sp_who2 and see what process is causing your problem.

Comment: @RichBenner
I executed 'exec sp_who2' and got few rows which contains my dbName.Please see below example.
580 - SPID
0 - EDID
sleeping - status
UserName - LoginName
FRCVD2161 - hostname
IOSMOC_DB - dbName
AWAITING COMMAND -cmd
0 - request_id
Please suggest

Comment: if you've got blocking then check the BlkBy column. It will show the process that is being blocked and the SPID of the process that is blocking it. You need to see what that SPID is doing and kill it if that's what you want to do.

Comment: @RichBenner
Sorry but how can i get to know what that SPID is doing ?
because that particular row shows me db name and status or may be currently none of the table is locked so i am not able to see ?

Comment: try running 'DBCC INPUTBUFFER(61)' with 61 replaced with your SPID

Answer (score 42):

Thank you Guys..
It is resolved.

I fired below query

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(P.object_id) AS TableName,
    Resource_type,
    request_session_id
FROM
    sys.dm_tran_locks L
JOIN
    sys.partitions P ON L.resource_associated_entity_id = p.hobt_id
WHERE   
    OBJECT_NAME(P.object_id) = 'P1Chronolog_IncidentActivityUpdates'
```

and killed that respective session by

```
Kill session_ID
```

Comment: Just a note to everyone finding this now: while you CAN just kill a lock like this, you really need to find out what's locking it and WHY. The point of locks is to prevent nasty bugs (look up "race conditions") so simply killing the locks with no idea what they are for is a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

Get the SPID of what is locking the table and kill it, see below

```
    SELECT      r.start_time [Start Time],session_ID [SPID],
            DB_NAME(database_id) [Database],
            SUBSTRING(t.text,(r.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
            CASE WHEN statement_end_offset=-1 OR statement_end_offset=0 
            THEN (DATALENGTH(t.Text)-r.statement_start_offset/2)+1 
            ELSE (r.statement_end_offset-r.statement_start_offset)/2+1
            END) [Executing SQL], 
            Status,command,wait_type,wait_time,wait_resource, 
            last_wait_type
FROM        sys.dm_exec_requests r
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) t
WHERE       session_id != @@SPID -- don't show this query
AND         session_id > 50 -- don't show system queries
ORDER BY    r.start_time


DBCC opentran()

exec sp_who2 68
exec sp_lock 68
kill 68
```

Comment: For me following commands worked
    DBCC opentran()

    exec sp_who2 68
    exec sp_lock 68
    kill 68